# AceFEM Solver Pauses/Freezes

Tags: acegen

I have been running many simulations using AceGen/AceFEM and I usually leave them to run while I work on something else. However, every so often I notice that the solver seems to pause/freeze on a load step. Simply clicking in the Mathematica window resumes the solving.

I wonder if anyone has noticed any similar behaviour?
Or has any idea what may be causing it?

The issue that can arise is if I leave a batch of simulations to run overnight it can pause during one of them at any point and then waste time until I wake up and resume then.

Any help/comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is by no means an elegant solution, but, using the application [Move Mouse](https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/p/move-mouse/9nq4ql59xlbf?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) and setting it to automatically move/click the mouse every 30 seconds prevents the AceFEM solver remaining paused for more than 30 seconds.